# python pandas sum by hour of day

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I'm working with the following dataset with hourly counts (df):
The datframe has 8784 rows (for the year 2016, hourly).

[image: dataframe (df)]

I'd like to see if there are daily trends (e.g if there is an increase in the morning hours. For this i'd like to create a plot that has the hour of the day (from 0 to 24) on the x-axis and number of cyclists on the y axis (something like in the picture below from http://ofdataandscience.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/capital-bikeshare-time-series-clustering.html).

[image]

I experimented with differet ways of `pivot`, `resample` and `set_index` and plotting it with matplotlib, without success. In other words, i couldn't find a way to sum up every observation at a certain hour and then plot those for each weekday

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can do `df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.hour)` and then `plot` against this IIUC

Comment: Are you trying to get an average of bikes rented at each hour for each weekday? and you want to plot them seperately. You could possibly look at creating a different dataframe for each weekday and then sum the hours after that via down sampling.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) and `weekday` and aggregate [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) (or maybe `mean`), last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.hour, 'weekday'])['Cyclists'].sum().unstack().plot()
```

Solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=df['Date'].dt.hour, 
                     columns='weekday', 
                     values='Cyclists', 
                     aggfunc='sum').plot()
```

Sample:

```
N = 200
np.random.seed(100)
rng = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=N, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Cyclists': np.random.randint(100, size=N)}) 
df['weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday_name
print (df.head())
   Cyclists                Date weekday
0         8 2016-01-01 00:00:00  Friday
1        24 2016-01-01 01:00:00  Friday
2        67 2016-01-01 02:00:00  Friday
3        87 2016-01-01 03:00:00  Friday
4        79 2016-01-01 04:00:00  Friday
```

---

```
print (df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.hour, 'weekday'])['Cyclists'].sum().unstack())
weekday  Friday  Monday  Saturday  Sunday  Thursday  Tuesday  Wednesday
Date                                                                   
0           102      91       120      53        95       86         21
1           102      83       100      27        20       94         25
2           121      53       105      56        10       98         54
3           164      78        54      30         8       42          6
4           163       0        43      48        89       84         37
5            49      13       150      47        72       95         58
6            24      57        32      39        30       76         39
7           127      76       128      38        12       33         94
8            72       3        59      44        18       58         51
9           138      70        67      18        93       42         30
10           77       3         7      64        92       22         66
11          159      84        49      56        44        0         24
12          156      79        47      34        57       55         55
13           42      10        65      53         0       98         17
14          116      87        61      74        73       19         45
15          106      60        14      17        54       53         89
16           22       3        55      72        92       68         45
17          154      48        71      13        66       62         35
18           60      52        80      30        16       50         16
19           79      43         2      17         5       68         12
20           11      36        94      53        51       35         86
21          180       5        19      68        90       23         82
22          103      71        98      50        34        9         67
23           92      38        63      91        67       48         92

df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.hour, 'weekday'])['Cyclists'].sum().unstack().plot()
```

[image: graph]

EDIT:

You can also convert `wekkday` to [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) for correct soting of columns by names of week:

```
names = [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df['weekday'] = df['weekday'].astype('category', categories=names, ordered=True)
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.hour, 'weekday'])['Cyclists'].sum().unstack().plot()
```

[image: graph1]

Comment: Super, glad can help you!

Comment: I find order of week names is incorrect, so I add solution for it. Check last edit.